# AWS Cloud search: Grouping search results by field value and returning only most popular of each

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I am using aws cloud search to search a group of docs. I want to group the results by a field value, say 'color', and return only one (most relevant) of each. So if i have

```
doc1 : {
  color: 'green',
  number: 3,
  relevance: 'high'
},
doc2 : {
  color: 'red',
  number: 3,
  relevance: 'medium'
},
doc3 : {
  color: 'green',
  number: 3,
  relevance: 'medium
}
```

And searching for 'number: 3, I only want doc1 and doc2, the most popular ones in their respective 'color' groups. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope :/ Ended up getting all results and truncating on the server side. Asked aws support about this and they told me it wasn't possible. That was half a year ago though, so might be worth double checking.

Comment: Ok thanks, I read a other question with similar question and find this one, can't find a way to do it...